# FFmpeg build error "openssl not found" (for iOS on Mac)

Tags: ios, build, ffmpeg, openssl

I want to build FFmpeg with --enable-openssl but it fails saying "Error: openssl not found", although I linked it within the build script (I'm using this https://github.com/DeviLeo/DLGPlayer/blob/master/How_to_build_ffmpeg_with_openssl.md).

openssl is not connected to FFmpeg as an **external library** as I can verify when calling

```
./configure --enable-openssl
```

within the ffmpeg folder in a terminal.

How can I set a folder as an external library?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile DeviLeo from the DLGPlayer project pointed me in the right direction in this thread: https://github.com/DeviLeo/DLGPlayer/issues/19

It seems I was using the wrong openssl version. He updated his build script and it's working without any problems.